# Power BI DATEADD In Date Calculation Causing Error

Tags: oracle, powerbi, dax, mdx

In Power BI, I am trying to create a simple new measure column in a table that calculates using the formula below.

```
TestColumn = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(MyTable[MyPrice]),
    DATEADD(MyTable[MyDate], -12, MONTH)
)
```

However, in trying to display this on a table, I receive the error shown below. It appears that there is an issue with my date column.

> MdxScript(Model) (28, 5) Calculation error in measure 'TestTable'[TestColumn]: A date column containing duplicate dates was specified in the call to function 'DATEADD'. This is not supported.

However, after testing it on another dataset, it appears to work, which leads me to believe that there is something wrong with the date field that I am bringing in. In the image below, the date column on the left is causing the error, whereas the column on the right works properly.

[image]

The column on the right is a date hierarchy, but the one on the left is not. Also worth noting: The data source for the column causing the error originates from an Oracle database, whereas the working one comes from SQL Server. Is there an easy fix to this error that I am receiving? Why is it that one of my date fields works with the formula, but the other does not?

Comment: Please only tag the database involved in the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are duplicate values in your table ( same date in multiple rows ). You are using time intelligence functions `DATEADD` which in DAX need a separate date table/dimension.

You could create a calendar table with unique and continuous dates that cover all periods of your fact table.